# Emulation keyboard for specific games python

Tags: python

i have such question:

I need press key in game GTA San Andreas, if be exactly, then in MTA (multi theft auto). I'am try such code:

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

W = 0x11
A = 0x1E
S = 0x1F
D = 0x20


# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

# directx scan codes http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (True):
        PressKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
        ReleaseKey(0x11)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Not working. also tried to use "pyautogui" and other - also not working. Can you help me?

Need to press such keys: W, A, S, D, 2. How i can did this?

Comment: This link may help you out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWqbl9IUdCg

Comment: I took this code from this video :D